# Am I using redigo HDEL correctly?

Tags: go, redis, redigo

I seem to have the correct usage for using the HDEL command interface, but seem to get 0 records deleted. Am I missing something here?

Here are useful code snippets:

**This doesn't work:**

```
keysToDeleteArr []string //this has valid key values from upstream

s.transClient.Do("MULTI")
_, err := s.transClient.Do("HDEL", myhash, keysToDeleteArr)
s.transClient.Do("EXEC")
```

Gives an output  (int64) 0 // # of keys deleted

**This does work:**

```
s.transClient.Do("MULTI")
for _, keyToDelete := range keysToDeleteArr {
  _, err := s.transClient.Do("HDEL", myhash, keyToDelete)
}
s.transClient.Do("EXEC")
```

Gives an output (int64) 1 for each HDEL. From the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/albertwidi/go-project-example/internal/pkg/redis/redigo#Redigo.HDel) and from static code analysis on the redigo lib, does seem like slices are acceptable parameters for `fields`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct an `[]interface{}` containing the command arguments. Pass the slice of `interface{}` to the Do method as a [variadic argument](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters):

```
args := make([]interface{}, 0, len(keysToDeleteArr) + 1)
args = append(args, myhash)
for _, v := range keysToDeleteArr {
    args = append(args, v)
}
 _, err := s.transClient.Do("HDEL", args...)
```

Use Redigo's [Args](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#Args) to execute the code above in a single line:

```
 _, err := s.transClient.Do("HDEL", redis.Args{}.Add(myhash).AddFlat(keysToDeleteArr)...)
```